# Calculating that 13 is a Wilson Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm confused by the idea of a Wilson Prime. The theorem states that $$p^2=(p-1)!+1$$

This makes sense for $5$: $$5^2=(4\times3\times2)+1$$  so $5^2=25$

But it makes no sense to me for $13$: $$13^2=4790016001$$
Clearly I am as far from a mathematician as possible. If you can help in very simple terms...

Comment: Which theorem states that $p^2=(p-1)!+1$? Wilson's theorem states that $p$ divides $(p-1)!+1$ for all primes $p$. A Wilson prime is a prime $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $(p-1)!+1$.

Answer (score 4):

A Wilson prime is a prime $p$ such that $p^2$ **divides** $(p-1)!+1$.

So you need to check that $169$ divides $12!+1$.

**Remark:** By Wilson's Theorem (called that despite the fact it was never proved by Wilson) $(p-1)!+1$ is always divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime. The prime $p$ is called a Wilson prime if $(p-1)!+1$ has at least one "extra" factor of $p$.

Comment: "...because it was never proved by Wilson" or "despite the fact that it was never proved by Wilson?"

Answer (score 3):

To prove that $13$ is a Wilson prime, you need to show that

$$12! \equiv -1 \pmod {13^2} \,.$$

To make the computations faster, observe that

$$12!= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot (2 \cdot 5)\cdot 11 \cdot (4 \cdot 3)$$

We split the product in three:

$$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4  \cdot 7 =(2  \cdot 7)(3 \cdot 4)=(13+1)(13-1)\equiv -1 \pmod {13^2}  $$
Also
$$6  \cdot 11 \cdot 8 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = (6 \cdot 11)(8 \cdot 8)=(5 \cdot 13+1)(5 \cdot 13-1) \equiv -1 \pmod{13^2}$$

and
$$ 5   \cdot 9 \cdot  \cdot 5  \cdot 3=25 \cdot 27=(2 \cdot 13-1)(2 \cdot 13+1) \equiv -1 \pmod {13^2} \,.$$

Multiplying we get

$$12! \equiv -1 \pmod{13^2} \,.$$