# Finding two odd primes with given conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find two odd primes     $ p\leq 13 $ for which the congruence $ (p - 1)! \cong   - 1 \pmod {p^2}$.
Try:  I have found that 5 is such a prime and I guess that the other one will be of the form $4k + 1$. But I can't establish this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3541564/edit) your question to show your attempt at solving this problem

Comment: there aren't very many odd primes $p\le 13$ to try

Comment: these are called [Wilson primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime); cf. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007540)

Comment: @ J. W. Tanner Thank you

Comment: also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266060/calculating-that-13-is-a-wilson-prime)

Comment: By the way: the $\equiv$ sign is \equiv, not \cong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv-1\bmod p$.

Primes $p$ satisfying $(p-1)!\equiv-1\bmod p^\color{blue}2$ are called [Wilson primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonPrime.html).

According to that link, the only known Wilson primes are $5, 13$, and $563$.

Answer (score 0):

Two primes 5 and 13 satisfy the given condition :

> $ p\leq 13 $ for which the congruence $ (p - 1)! \cong   - 1 \pmod {p^2}$.